# Xgboost time series model does not capture trend

Tags: python, time-series, xgboost, trend

I am building a churn forecast model using features such as 1 year worth lags, holidays, moving averages, day/day ratios, seasonality factor extracted from statsmodels etc. It is clearly not an additive series, the magnitude of holiday churn each year is greater than that in previous years.

My XGB model predicts daily churn quite accurately, but it fails on holidays miserably (the trenches are slightly better predicted as compared to peaks):
[image]

in my opinion the model is unable to capture the exponential nature of the series. here is how it looks like at present. is there a way i can capture the exponential nature of the series, by using any additional features or something?

[image]

Comment: Tree models do not capture the trend because they do not work well on out of sample data. The model has learnt the trend in the actuals w.r.t to date, through its splits, [which is each day:this value] . For everyday in future, it stays the same, cause the future date does not fall in any of its seen buckets, it just splits out a mean value for that date, in combination with other attributes.